# How to use Microsoft Access database file online for asp.net web application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, ms-access, web-applications

I have Access database file with tables in it, I used this Access database file for my application as local database and now I want to upload this file somewhere and use it in my application online. 
Is there any way to upload this Access database file and use it online for web application as a database?

Comment: You can upload this file to the same server as your web application.

Comment: How to give Data Source(location of file) if I keep access database file in my application folder?

Comment: Use a path to the file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can not understand what you say. I think you can put this Access database file to the server where web application online locate in.

Comment: What will be the location for the file in Data Source(Connection String) if I keep Access file in my application folder?

Comment: Connection String is your application folder  (which includes your access file ) absolute path

Comment: I have folder like this: myFolder/Database/Example.accdb and i have given location in connection string like this: connectionString="Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=Database\Example.accdb; User Id=*****; Password="
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"

Comment: It's not working. Is there any specific way to give location in Data Source?

Comment: Data Source= Absolute path;  your path  is not Complete paht, you should write for example : "D:\myFolder\Database\Example.accdb".

Comment: please display you write path.

Comment: You also can use relative path. For example :   "./Database/Example.accdb".

Comment: you could find some information about absolute path and relative path. Use absolute path is easier, but It is not recommended to do so. Best is use relative path.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129597/discussion-between-manga-srinivas-rao-baipalli-and-superman).